# Python - replace the startswith character

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to replace the first character in each line from the text file.

```
 2 1.510932 0.442072 0.978141 0.872182
 5 1.510932 0.442077 0.978141 0.872181
```

Above is my text file.

```
import sys
import glob
import os.path

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/txt/23.txt')

for file_name in list_of_files:
    f= open(file_name, 'r')
    lst = []
    for line in f:
            f = open(file_name , 'w')
            if line.startswith("2 "):
               line = line.replace("2 ","7")
            f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

What i want:-

If the number starting with **2**, i want to change that into **7**. The problem is that, In the same line multiple **7** is there. If i change startswith character and save everything was changing

Thanks

Comment: You're opening a file to write (i.e. erasing it first) while you're reading it. Write into a new file instead.

Comment: @eumiro I want to write in same file

Comment: @AshokP then open it as ```'a'``` not ```'w'```

Comment: @AshokP you want to replace the lines. Write into a new file and then rename it to the original filename. Or read everything into the memory, update, and then write into the same file overwriting it. Reading line after line and writing these lines won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
for file_name in list_of_files:
    data = []
    with open(file_name) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith("2 "):              #Check line
                line = " ".join(['7'] + line.split()[1:])   #Update line
            data.append(line)

    with open(file_name, "w") as outfile:     #Write back to file
        for line in data:
            outfile.write(line+"\n")
```

Comment: Storing everything in memory is a sure way to kill your computer when the file is huge. This code would never pass a code review here.

Answer (score 1):

The **proper** solution is (pseudo code):

```
open sourcefile for reading as input
open temporaryfile for writing as output
for each line in input:
    fix the line
    write it to output
close input
close output
replace sourcefile with temporaryfile
```

We use a temporary file and write along to avoid potential memory errors.

I leave it up to you to translate this to Python (hint: that's quite straightforward).